# Offline timezone database library for microcontrollers

Tags: open-source, library, embedded-systems, timezones, microcontroller

In the process of planning a deeply embedded system that has no internet access, but a GPS receiver, I need to find a way to convert GPS time to local time.  I'm assuming knowledge of the local time zone here¹.

#### Hard Requirements

- **Target Architecture** 
  Cortex-M4F and/or RISC-V
- **Operating System** 
   Freestanding/Baremetal or FreeRTOS compatible. This *probably* means distribution as C, C++ (without exceptions) or Rust source code.
   Generally, a `malloc`-free implementation would be *vastly* preferable.
- **Resource Constraints** 
   less than 512 kB of RAM available, < 300 kB or program space
- **License Constraints** 
   MPL/BSD/Apache/MIT/LGPL and GPLv3 are all fine, generally "OSI-approved *Open Source* license"

#### Soft Requirements

- Compressed timezone file format
- Tool to convert "official" tzinfo data to embedded format (if not same format)
- Stylistically, at least C99, C++11 or Rust

Before I start ripping out `localtime` code from newlib or dietlib and get tangled in where these use scratchpad memory, I wondered whether someone had a recommendation for such a library

---

¹ e.g., the user selects "Europe/Lissabon" manually from a list, or I find a way to convert GPS coordinates to time zones, but that's not in-scope for this question

Comment: as variant https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date . you can find by  key 'c++ timezone library'